# Excel If statement true in A7 add a set value on the value of E7

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a small excel sheet that will help with my financial problems and i'm trying create a calculation to see if the date is a thursday if so add £10 onto the outgoings column.

I need to keep the outgoing columns free so i can edit and change the data but i need it to always add £10 onto what i enter.

I have B7 as a thursday and its returning true from this function run in column A7

```
  =IF(WEEKDAY(B9, 2)=4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Now i can get the value of E7 (Outgoings) and add 10 to it but it saves it in A7 i need it to save that value in E7.

Comment: you can't change another cell value using formulas in that way. You need VBA

Comment: you literally need to call the function from `E7` if you want it to change. It's not possible to modify other cells content using formulas just like simoco said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **simoco's** comment, here is a sample macro:

```
Sub BumpIt()
    If Range("B7").Value = True Then
        v = Range("E7").Value + 10
        Range("E7").Value = v
        Range("A7").Value = v
    End If
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!